# Changing Hues of Multiple Images

Tags: javascript, html, css

While there are codes available to change the hue of an image just once or twice, I would like to:
a. Change hue of multiple images 
b. Applying different hues in a loop
c. Gradual changing of the hues rather than suddenly

```
<img src="parrots.jpg">
<img src="flowers.jpg">
<img src="rainbow.jpg">
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Yes. It is Possible.

Comment: Please share the code !

Comment: Share what code?  I don't have any code for this. You just asked if it was possible. The answer is yes. You're expected to make the attempt here. Not the rest of us. Go make your attempt at this. And when you've failed, come back here and share *your* code and ask for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Robert, I have tried multiple codes but couldn't do it. Thats why I am here.

Comment: Then share what you've tried and where your hangups are. SO is not a code writing service where you just come here and announce what you want and expect people to write code for you for free that you can paste into your own work. YOU are expected to make the effort.

Comment: Thanks Robert, your comments inspired me to take the initiative and after intense efforts, I could achieve it!

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

A

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img')
imgs.forEach((img)=>{
   img.style.filter = 'hue-rotate(-77deg)'
});
```

B

```
 for(i in imgs){
     if(i % 2 === 0)
        imgs[i].style.filter = 'hue-rotate(-77deg)';
     }else{
        imgs[i].style.filter = 'hue-rotate(40deg)';
     }
 }
```

C

```
for(var i=0; i<10; 1++){
 setInterval(()=>{
    imgs[0].style.filter = 'hue-rotate('+ i * 360/10+'deg)'
  }, 300)
}
```

This are approaches rather than actual code, it's not tested, in case you've got an error, go to the console and start debugging and add more code as you need it, hopefully it will give you an idea